# HTML/JQuery: How to open a file; without flashing new tab; and retaining current page state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a link on click of which a file gets downloaded.

On Client's Machine:

1) On some systems; The IE or Firefox have plugin to display PDF inside browser; on click of link.

2) On some systems, The IE do not have plugin; so when we click link; a new tab flash for a second and file get downloaded with option dialog of save/save as open etc.

Following is the way link is getting opened; so that the state of page should be retained:

```
<a href="http://www.gasl.org/refbib/Bible_King_James_Version.pdf" target="_blank">Holy Bible</a>
```

**Now Requirements**:

Query 1: Client do not want to remove plugin from browser and want to get file downloaded with dialog. Is it possible?

Query 2 (Important):
Can we download file; so that new tab does not get flash and file gets downloaded?

**Update**:
Can not remove target attribute as if i will remove that and if plugin is still there in browsers then the page state will not be retained at all.

Comment: For Query 2 (Important): Remove target="_blank" from anchor tag

Comment: I don't see any relation with Jquery nor Javascript. Why not link to `download.php?file=[FILEID]` and set some headers to force download? The blank (flash, as you say) window is because of your `target="_blank"`. You can dot it also with .htaccess file un your refbib folder.

Comment: @ArunKumarM 

Updated question. Let us take this case if plugin is still installed and if i remove target attribute then PDF gets loaded in same page and the work which user is doing is gone. This is not required at all.

Comment: @orugari :

No, if plugin remain there in browser then pdf gets opened in same page which is again a problem. The reason we used target=_blank

Comment: @orugari 

In continuation to above comment: Also don't understand last line; what it means 'You can dot it also with .htaccess file un your refbib folder'

Answer (score 0):

**PHP:**

In your link, set the href to "download.php?file=file.pdf or any ID from a database, or just the file name, whatever.
Create a download.php file with:

```
$path = path/of/the/file/; 
$filename = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
readfile($path);
```

Comment: O so it requires a server side call? Can't we resolve it on client side only?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible on client side.

Comment: Looks to me the same. So with this; the page will remain as it is and file gets downloaded separately and will not open in same page; if plugin is installed.

Comment: Did you even tried? Seriously. The php version FORCE the download, it does not load on web browser.

Comment: Thanks.
I can understand that with server side i can get response as you mentioned.

Comment: If my answer solve your problem, please mark it, thanks.

Comment: OK. I will. I am trying some client side methods, if unable to then this will be the answer :)